# Stacked scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot, stacked

Is it possible to have the scatter plot below stacked by “sex” and grouped by day similar to the bar graph in the background?

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df = px.data.tips()

# Scatter Plot
fig = px.strip(df, x='day', y='tip', color='sex').update_traces(jitter = 1)

# Female bars
fig.add_bar(name='Female',
            x=['Sun', 'Sat', 'Thur', 'Fri'], y=[5, 6, 7, 8], marker_color='rgba(0,0,255,0.2)'
           )
# Male bars
fig.add_bar(name='Male',
            x=['Sun', 'Sat', 'Thur', 'Fri'], y=[8, 2, 4, 6], marker_color='rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
           )

# Make bars stacked
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')

fig.show()
```

[image: Stacked bar graph non-stacked scatter plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stripmode='overlay'` does the job.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df = px.data.tips()

# Scatter Plot
fig = px.strip(df, x='day', y='tip', color='sex', stripmode='overlay').update_traces(jitter = 1)


# Female bars
fig.add_bar(name='Female',
            x=['Sun', 'Sat', 'Thur', 'Fri'], y=[5, 6, 7, 8], marker_color='rgba(0,0,255,0.2)'
           )

# Male bars
fig.add_bar(name='Male',
            x=['Sun', 'Sat', 'Thur', 'Fri'], y=[8, 2, 4, 6], marker_color='rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
           )

# Make bars stacked
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')

fig.show()
```

Gives

[image: Stacked scatter plot]

Comment: I'm just curious... Are you *really* answering your own question here? I was considering `stripmode='overlay'` when you first posted your question, but though that would not cover the `"stacked" scatter` part. If you're  happy with this, that's fine. But if you for some reason would actually like to *`stack`* the scatter traces, let me know.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what, in your opinion, is not covered with `stripmode='overlay'`? Could you perhaps post a picture? I don't think I understand (the bars are just there for explanatory reasons). It's good enough for me, yes; however, I am still not entirely sure whether I should use `overlay` or `group` for the final graph, but with `group` I cannot solve the error bar problem, see https://community.plotly.com/t/scatter-plot-with-conditional-error-bars/48297/2?u=windrose if you are interested. I know that is another issue, but any suggestions would be very much appreaciated. Thanks.