# Plotly strip plot: avoid spacing between colors in px.strip

Tags: python, plotly, strip

The second example in https://plotly.com/python/strip-charts/ shows adding color (see screenshot below), but this automatically also creates spacing between the red and blue colored dots.

[image]

How do I turn that off? How do I make sure my dots are colored for a categorical variable, without making two separate 'strips'?

Comment: Possible duplicate/related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65645424/680068

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `stripmode='overlay'` option. It should produce the following.

Data points overlayed:

[image]